# How do I make a copy of LPCWSTR?

Tags: c++, c

What are the steps I have to take to duplicate a LPCWSTR string?

Consider the case: `LPCWSTR str = L"Copy me";`

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate the string? The current variable points to a constant string so there should be no lifetime issue. If you need to manipulate the copy, in C++, you'd be better off using a string class for the copy.

Comment: @Charles Bailey If I do `LPCWSTR str2 = str;` Is it going to make a copy just like the primitives?

Comment: Well, you're going to have a copy of the pointer which will point to the same fixed string (which cannot legitimately be modified). `LPCWSTR` is a pointer type in disguise. I'm not sure what you mean by "just like the primitives".

Comment: @Charles Bailey That phrase was refering to the fact that if I have `int x = 20;` and I do `x2 = x;`. Then a copy of `x` will be assigned to `x2` Would LPCWSTR work the same way?

Comment: Yes, although the copy is, in this case, a duplicated pointer rather than a duplicated `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `wcscpy()`.  Here is the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663(v=vs.90).aspx

A safer variant is `wcscpy_s()`.  You have to allocate a buffer that is big enough to hold the copy up front:

```
   LPCWSTR str = L"Copy me";
   std::vector<wchar_t> thecopy( wcslen(str) + 1 ); // add one for null terminator
   wcscpy_s(thecopy.data(), thecopy.size(), str);

   // you can get a pointer to the copy this way:
   LPCWSTR *strCopy = thecopy.data();
```

wcscpy_s()'s documentation can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: This isn't complete, you don't show how to initialize `szTarget` to point to something appropriate for the `wcscpy` call.

Comment: Good point.  Added that in, and also mentioned wcscpy_s(), which is better.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`wcscpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscpy/)

```
LPWSTR wcscpy(LPWSTR szTarget, LPWCSTR szSource);
```

Target is non-constant wide-string (LPWSTR), and source is constant-wide-string.

`LPCWSTR` is defined as

```
typedef const WCHAR* LPCWSTR;
```

> LP - Pointer
>   C - Constant
>   WSTR - Wide character String

Comment: This isn't complete, you don't show how to initialize `szTarget` to point to something appropriate for the `wcscpy` call.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `LPCWSTR` is equvivalent to `const wchar_t *` then for GNU systems you can use [`wcsdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wcsdup.3.html):

```
wchar_t * wcsdup(const wchar_t * s);
```

The function is also defined by `POSIX.1-2008`.

Comment: Except that it's only available as [`_wcsdup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc(v=vs.110).aspx) from Visual C++.